# Unable to get network connection on VM in TrueNAS-12.0-U8

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, troubleshooting, freenas, truenas

I'm attempting to create an Ubuntu VM in TrueNAS (which uses bhyve), but nothing I try will allow the VM to obtain an IP address.

I think there has to be something misconfigured on the host, because I've tried installing 3 different OS variations -Ubuntu 20.04.4 server, Ubuntu 20.04.4 desktop, and FreePBX16 (based on CentOS 7.8.2003). Most of my troubleshooting efforts have been within the Ubuntu 20 server.

None of the installers got a network connection either, so it doesn't seem to be a consequence of deleting the CD-ROM device that has the installation ISO mounted. At any rate, the interface shown by `ip a` matches interface in `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`.

- Host is running TrueNAS-12.0-U8
- Jails on the same system are able to access the network without issue.
- No VLANS are configured on the network
- The host's physical interface I want to use is `igb0`

[image: interfaces screenshot]

- The "NIC" device for the VMS are configured to use igb0 and VirtIO adapter. Have also tried the Intel adapter, but it didn't help.

[image: NIC settings]

- The "predictable interface name" shown by `ip a` matches interface in /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml. In cases where it had to be corrected, `netplan apply` didn't fix it. But if I change the device order before first boot, they match from the start.

[image: results of ip a]

[image: contents of netplan yaml file]

- Pinging any IP address returns `ping: connect: Network is unreachable`, so of course pinging any domain returns `ping: <domain>: Temporary failure in name resolution`
- `ip route` returns nothing
- The "Delay VM Boot until VNC Connects" option in the VM configuration is disabled.
- I even tried flushing the host's arp cache (`arp -d -a`) because I found a forum post somewhere that said it had helped them

I'm running out of ideas of other remedies to attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it refused to work with interface igb0, but when I reconfigured the NIC device to use the other ethernet port (igb1) everything started to work as expected.